# A flexible running schedule generator (Asics)

Tags: preparation, running

About 8 years ago I ran a marathon and I used an online running schedule generator from Asics.
To help a friend, I tried to search for it, but I cannot find it anymore.

Does anybody know if there is a similar or equal generator?

It was capable of creating a schedule based on the time until a running event, the amount of days per week to train, the requested time and the distance (among some other variables).

Comment: Try the Asics app - Runkeeper. I'm not sure that it does full training programs for free, but it can certainly do them.

Comment: @bob1 Thanks I will check into it